# Custom formatting of parts and chapters in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I want same format of table of content in my dissertation as given in the attached image of table of content of a book. I am having few problems:
i) Part number and name are not aligned in center.
ii) I want in each part chapter number should start from 1.
iii) I also want to add page range in front of each chapter name.
iv) I want chapter and pages label on the top for each part separately.    [image: Index image]

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty, explicit,raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
{\thepart\hspace{1em}}
{\MakeUppercase{\partname}\ \thepart\hspace{1em}}
{}{}
\makeatother%must add before hyperref package

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
 }
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}%must add after hyperref package
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcommand\cpart[1]{\part[\hfill#1\hfill]{#1}}


\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{CHAPTERS}\hfill \textbf{PAGES}\par}


\def\topic#1{
\section*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter*{}
\vskip-1in
\topic{Introduction}
Some text here.

\chapter*{}\vskip-1in
\topic{Problem statement}
Some text here.

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\cpart{First Part name}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{page}}
\chapter{First Chapter name} 
\section {Section name}
\newpage
\section {Section name}

\chapter{Second Chapter name} 
\section {Section name}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\cpart{Second Part name}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{page}}
\chapter{First Chapter name} 
\section {Section name}

\chapter{Second Chapter name} 
\section {Section name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: @PeterWilson I have added a basic structure of my code. I am not getting the exact output what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest scanning ctan a little bit, e.g. for this topic: https://ctan.org/topic/toc-etc . At least one of your 4 tasks can be handled by an appropriate package. E.g. tocstyle might be a candidate to achive what you sketched.

Comment: Thank you. I hope someone else can help you.